# Enable .exe to run at startup

Tags: windows-7, boot

I use GmailNotifierPlus for mail notifications, and I currently have to click the icon every time my computer starts to start it. How do you enable the .exe to run at startup?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Add a Link to the Startup Folder**

> Click the Windows "Start" button and
>   select "All Programs." Right-click the
>   "Startup" folder in the menu and
>   select "Open All Users." This option
>   opens the folder for all users on the
>   computer. Choose "Explore" to open the
>   folder for the currently logged-in
>   user only.
>
> Right-click the folder or file you
>   want started when the computer boots.
>   Select "Copy Shortcut" from the menu.
>
> Right-click any white space in the
>   "Startup" folder opened in Step 1.
>   Select "Paste" from the menu list. The
>   program will now open the next time
>   you start the computer.

**Change Current Startup Programs**

> Click the Windows "Start" button and
>   type "msconfig" in the search textbox.
>   This opens the System Configuration
>   console.
>
> Click the "Startup" tab. This gives
>   you a view of all the programs
>   installed as a startup option on your
>   computer.
>
> Check boxes of the applications you
>   want to start when you boot the
>   computer. For programs you no longer
>   want to start, clear the checkbox.
>
> Click "Apply" and close the
>   configuration window. A popup window
>   asks if you want to reboot the
>   computer. Click "Restart" to reboot
>   the computer and save the changes.

*[Source](http://www.ehow.com/how_5215115_change-startup-programs-windows.html)*

Comment: But I bet there will be some checkbox in Options or when you installed that app, that will do the same automatically.

Comment: don't be so lazy!!! :) +1

Comment: Ok, ok, I'm sorry! :D It's just that, that way, I feel like I'm stealing that info, it looks like I knew it while I just used google... The "Source" link is sooo small, some might overlook it. :)

Comment: Er, I mean "This way". English...

Comment: But if that link dies, so does your answer! SU is against just linking on principal, I think you'd be forgiven if somebody doesn't notice the source link :P

Comment: I knew about the risk of "404" but... Well, Ok. :)

Comment: nah, you don't 'steal the info' as long as have the decency to credit the source :)

Comment: there's no options to enable it at startup within the app itself, it's a pretty bare bones thing that is useful with the win7 taskbar. thanks, i hope it works

Comment: After following your instructions, I unfortunately still get a dialog after boot confirming that I want to run the program. Can I bypass this dialog and make the the program truthfully autostart?

Comment: The folder is hidden under `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` in Windows >=8.

Answer (score 3):

Windows task scheduler was written for this purpose. It can start any task based on some criteria or event (like system startup). It will record its status and last run info.
In Win7, click: start -> control panel -> administration tools -> Task Scheduler.
The wizard "Create basic task wizard" is self obvious.